# Get all remaining items with GetRange

Tags: c#, linq, list, syntactic-sugar

Recently, I've got interested in the `List.GetRange()` function. It can retrieve a sub-list from a bigger list. Usage requires **two arguments**:

```
List<T> SubList = List<T>.GetRange(10, 20) //Get 20 items, starting from index 10
```

But what if I wanted to take **every remaining** item from a specific index, with this function?

```
List<T> RemainingItemsFromList = MyList.GetRange(7, /*REST*/) //What can I insert into REST to make it retrieve everything?
```

Is there

- Any built-in `RestOfTheList` statement without doing something like `Length - Index`?
- Any replacement function (that already exists)?
- Any other alternative?

or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: `list.Count - start`, e.g. `MyList.Count - 7`

Comment: You can use LINQ's Skip(7).ToList(), but that will be a bit less efficient.

Comment: @IvanStoev I specified in the question I do not want to do `Length - Index`.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess you want too much. And LINQ `Skip` is so trivial that I would never assume someone will ask for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `List` does not provide built-in method with required functionality, your options are:

1) Create extension method yourself:

```
public static class ListExtensions {
    public static List<T> GetRange<T>(this List<T> list, int start) {
        return list.GetRange(start, list.Count - start);
    }
}

var remaining = list.GetRange(7);
```

2) Use LINQ:

```
var remaining = list.Skip(7).ToList(); // a bit less efficient, but usually that does not matter
```